# Checking the existence of a command line argument in shell

Tags: shell

I want to check if a command line option exists when running a shell script, example

```
./test.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

Want to check if one of the argument is say arg3 (not necessarily the third argument)

The quick solution is to use a for loop and check if one of the argument matches a given string, but is there a better way to do it something of the form 'arg3' in $@.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(assuming bash)

I would do this:

```
have_arg3=false
for arg; do
    if [[ $arg == "arg3" ]]; then
        have_arg3=true
        break
    fi
done
if $have_arg3; then
    echo "arg3 is present
fi
```

but you could do this (all quotes and spaces below are required!):

```
if [[ " $* " == *" arg3 "* ]]; then
    echo "arg3 is present"
fi
```

---

can be encapsulated in a function:

```
$ arg_in_args () (
    arg=$1
    shift
    IFS=:
    [[ "$IFS$*$IFS" == *"$IFS$arg$IFS"* ]]
)
$ set -- foo bar baz
$ if arg_in_args "arg3" "$@"; then echo Y; else echo N; fi
N
$ if arg_in_args "baz" "$@"; then echo Y; else echo N; fi
Y
```

Comment: The first solution will work; the second solution may not work if arguments can contain spaces (or whatever you try to use to separate arguments).